# How can I get an error or a warning from a PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I had an update like this:

```
update table set col1=?,col2=?,col3=? where col4=?;
```

and I filled it up like this:

```
statement.setString(1,"some_value");
statement.setString(2,"some_value");
statement.setString(3,"some_value");
```

and I forgot to add a fourth value.I did a `executeUpdate` and of course nothing happened to the database. I spent about 1 hour debugging it, to see where it goes wrong. I then modified my code to print the `SQLWarning` object returned by the `getWarnings` method. 
It always returned null. I even modified the code to the buggy state it was, before I set the fourth parameter, and still no warning. Does anyone know how one can get an error/warning?

If it matters, my Connection is set to autoCommit.

Comment: is your code catching and swallowing exceptions?

Comment: no, all the exceptions are printed with a full stack trace.

Comment: This is apparently JDBC driver specific or a "bug" in SQLite JDBC driver. To my experience, MySQL and PostgreSQL both throws a self-explaining SQLException if a parameter is missing. MySQL for example would have thrown `java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 4` here.

Comment: @BalusC is that exception thrown on auto-commit too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`executeUpdate` returns the number of rows modified by the statement.  You can check to see if this result is `0`, and if it is, then log your own warning.